# Using Cassandra User Defined Type in a MAP Data Type Column

Tags: database, dictionary, cassandra

Can you use a Cassandra User Defined Type (UDT) as the value of a map data type column?

For example:

`CREATE TYPE message_record( message text, update_time timestamp );`

`CREATE TABLE user_records( user_account int, user_record map<text, FROZEN<message_record> );`

I then want to insert into the table as shown in this (undoubtedly incorrect) command.  I've tried all sorts of permutations and my editor (DevCenter) doesn't like any of them.

```
INSERT INTO user_records (user_account, user_record) Values ( 
1234, 
[ {'0' : {message : 'message 1', update_time : '2021-06-08T18:00:05.000'}}, 
  {'1' : {message : 'message 2', update_time :'2021-06-08T18:01:05.000'}}, 
  {'2' : {message : 'message 3', update_time :'2021-06-08T18:02:05.000'}} 
];
```

I'm trying to avoid normalizing my data into different tables.  I want to be able to add additional elements to the map as time goes on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax - in your case you are trying to insert it as list of maps, but you need just map. You need to use it as following:

```
INSERT INTO user_records (user_account, user_record) Values ( 
1234, 
{'0' : {message : 'message 1', update_time : '2021-06-08T18:00:05.000'}, 
'1' : {message : 'message 2', update_time :'2021-06-08T18:01:05.000'}, 
'2' : {message : 'message 3', update_time :'2021-06-08T18:02:05.000'}});
```